# How to display self-employed on LinkedIn experience

Tags: linkedin

I've been looking for a solution on how I can display my self-employed experience like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

> ### Showing Self-Employed or Consultant on Your Profile
>
> You can update the following areas on your profile to show that you're self-employed, a consultant or an independent contractor:
>
> - Edit your [Professional Headline](https://www.linkedin.com/profile/edit-basic-info). Enter something like "Self-employed - Internet Consulting".
> - Edit your profile [Summary](https://www.linkedin.com/profile/edit-summary).
> - [Add a position](https://www.linkedin.com/profile/edit-position) in the **Experience** section.
>
> When you add a position:
>
> 1. Type "Self-Employed" in the **Company Name** field or add the name of the company at which you were a consultant.
>      **Important**: After you type this, move your cursor outside of the **Company Name** field and click your mouse to prevent pulling in any dropdown options. If you didn't do this, click **Cancel** and try again.
> 2. Type something like "Independent Professional" in the **Title** field.
> 3. Click **Save Changes**.

[Source](https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1281).